# I had en error with this code which includes Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton

class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        btn_flat = MDFlatButton(text='Hello World')
        screen.add_widget(btn_flat)
        return btn_flat


DemoApp().run()
```

I think I import wrong module or something.

This is the first time I am using Kivy.

When I run the code it opens up the window but immediately closes the window.

After that it gives me this error.

Thanks to all StackOverflow community

*Below is the error*

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Toshiba/Desktop/python_temelleri/Kivy.py", line 14, in <module>
     DemoApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\python_temelleri\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 837, in run
     Window.add_widget(self.root)
   File "C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\python_temelleri\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1297, in add_widget
     (widget, widget.parent)
 kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <kivymd.uix.button.MDFlatButton object at 0x000000296765DF98> to window, it already has a parent <Screen name=''>
```

Comment: I found the error.I just type btn_flat to the return part but I would type screen.But anyways if anyone same the same error answer now you know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the kivy `App` code does:

```
        Window.add_widget(self.root)
```

where `self.root` is whatever is returned by your `build()` method. So if your `build()` method does

```
screen.add_widget(btn_flat)
```

and

```
return btn_flat
```

Then the above code from the kivy `App` will through an error since `btn_flat` is already a child of the `screen`. Your `build()` method should probably be:

```
def build(self):
    screen = Screen()
    btn_flat = MDFlatButton(text='Hello World')
    screen.add_widget(btn_flat)
    return screen
```